# Possible to rewrite url clientside with javascript without reloading page

Tags: javascript

Is it possible to rewrite the URL in the URL-field on the client's browser?

So when a person clicks on a link on my page something ajax happens (eg a tab shows up) i want the url to display the action without refreshing the page.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can change the hash/anchor part of the URL (after #). The rest of the URL is readonly.

```
location.hash = "#value";
```

Answer (score 25):

When everyone else answered this question, they were right, it wasn't possible to change the URL in javascript. With HTML5 and modern browsers, it now is using the `HTML5 History API`

[diveintohtml5.info article](http://diveintohtml5.info/history.html) about it. [Here](http://html5doctor.com/history-api/) is another good blog post explaining the feature.

Check [caniuse.com](http://caniuse.com/#feat=history) for browser compatability.

There are libraries such as [History.js](https://github.com/browserstate/history.js) which wrap the API and pollyfill using hashbangs for old browsers.

Answer (score 9):

URL *rewriting* is not possible, but it is very common to append action data with a hash. For example, Facebook uses it extensively:

```
http://www.facebook.com/#!/username
                        ^
```

Everything after the hash is just anchor data in the same page, which you can modify by script all day long.

Newer browsers also offer the [onhashchanged event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.onhashchange) so you can react to the "URL" changing instead of polling it constantly.

Comment: This on is very nice! I'm going to remember it for future projects. But i'm resorting to an other solution.

Answer (score 0):

The only possible solution is to append an anchor. Then you can use somwething like [reallysimplehistory](http://code.google.com/p/reallysimplehistory/) to allow the user to bookmark a page or use the back button within you ajaxified page.

I have done that with a tabbed page in the past, too.