# How to refresh page and append URL parameter?

Tags: html

When a certain webpage loads, I'd like to append a URL parameter to the page URL without having to know the full URL path.

I've tried this but it didn't work:

```
<a href="javascript:location.href?param=1">test link</a>
```

When I click the link, nothing happens.  Any ideas how this can be done?

The above is meant to refresh the page and I can then capture the parameter.

Comment: Similar question can be found here at [THIS][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2944500/possible-to-rewrite-url-clientside-with-javascript-without-reloading-page

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try

```
<a href="?param=1">test link</a>
```